# How to pass nested JSON from dataframe while adding another field?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe that I need to pass as a nested json string into an email service provider api as a json string.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
email_address     first_name       last_name
a@a.com            adam             apple
b@b.com            bobby            banana
```

The contacts in the dataframe is what I need to pass into the email service provider API, and this needs be a nested JSON string like so:

```
{
    "import_data": [{
        "email_addresses": ["hector@hector.com"],
        "first_name": "Hector",
        "last_name": "Smith"
    }, {
        "email_addresses": ["Jane@Doe.com"],
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe"
    }, {
        "email_addresses": ["Pradeep@Patel.com"],
        "first_name": "Pradeep",
        "last_name": "Patel"
    }],
    "lists": ["1234567890"]
}
```

I am not sure how I would create nested json string via the 'to_json' command from pandas and at the same time insert the word **"import_data"** as above into the json string. I know I can hard code the  a column with in the dataframe for **"lists"** and pass that in as well. List ID will always be static.

Here is code for my API response:

```
headers = {

    'Authorization': '',
    'X-Originating-Ip': '',
    'Content-Type': '',

    }

update_contact = '{"import_data": [{"email_addresses": ["test@test.com"],"first_name": "test","last_name": "test"},{"email_addresses": ["Jane@Doe.com"],"first_name": "Jane","last_name": "Doe"}, {"email_addresses": ["Pradeep@Patel.com"],"first_name": "Pradeep","last_name": "Patel"}],"lists": ["1234567890"]}'

r = requests.post('url', headers=headers ,data = update_contact)

print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the data using `orient='records'` of `to_dict()`, then just format your the dictionary to json

```
#converted emails to list, may not be necessary...
df.email_address = df.email_address.apply(lambda x: [x])

import json

update_contact = json.dumps({'import_data':df.to_dict(orient='records'),
                             'lists':["1234567890"]})
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the API asked for application/json, if this is really the case, you should send it like this

```
headers = {}

update_contact = {"import_data": [{"email_addresses": ["test@test.com"],"first_name": "test","last_name": "test"},{"email_addresses": ["Jane@Doe.com"],"first_name": "Jane","last_name": "Doe"}, {"email_addresses": ["Pradeep@Patel.com"],"first_name": "Pradeep","last_name": "Patel"}],"lists": ["1234567890"]}

r = requests.post('url', headers=headers ,json= update_contact)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: let me test that out. and you are correct can use application/json

Comment: and because you didn't set any headers, you can just send it without the headers keyword argument @RustyShackleford

Comment: that works just fine, but how do I pass in many rows from my dataframe and insert the word 'import_data" only once?

Comment: @RustyShackleford you can try `update_contact['import_data'].append(yourRow)`

Comment: I have been playing around with this last few days. My issue is that I need to pass the phrase 'import_data' once and list ID once. When I hardcode list_id into the 'lists' column, every row gets the list_id. How do I only pass 'import_data' once and 'lists' once? 

I am not sure what you mean by (yourrow). I will have more than 2 people in the dataframe so the approach needs to be scalable to thousands of users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_variable.append(NewValues)   so that it will append any of your data blocks into a json value.
Refer to below skeleton and re-build according to your inputs.

```
enter code here


import json
Json_List=[]

for i in Excel_data:
    Newdata = {
    'Name':Read_name_From_Excel(i),
    'Age':Read_age_From_Excel(i),
    'Email':Read_Email_From_Excel(i),
    'Amount':Read_Amount_From_Excel(i)
    }

    Json_List.append(Newdata)
```